# Elasticsearch search with matchQuery using fuzziness and shingle analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with *elasticsearch* and coming up with such a problem.
I defined an *analyzer* with type of shingle and create a mapping.

Here's the code:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "icons": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings_path": "analysis/char_filter.txt"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "synonym_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym_filter.txt"
                },
                "shingle_filter":{
                    "type":"shingle",
                    "max_shingle_size": 2,
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "output_unigrams": true,
                    "token_separator": ""
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "synonym_filter",
                        "shingle_filter"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": [
                        "icons"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type-0": {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I put a document in the index.

```
{
   "text":"hello"
}
```

After this I start to search like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "text":{
                "query":"hell world",
                "fuzziness":1
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

but it matches nothing.
then I change my query to:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "text":{
                "query":"world hell",
                "fuzziness":1
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

this request get the document.

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.21576157,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index-001",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.21576157,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "hello"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My elasticsearch version is 6.2.4

Anyone can tell me the reason?

[image: condition in kibana]

[image: analyze result of hell world]

[image: analyze result of hell]

[image: analyze result of world hell]

[image: analyze result of hello]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fuzziness` with a combination of `shingle_filter` is causing the issue. If you read the note from [fuzziness in match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness)

> Fuzzy matching is not applied to terms with synonyms or **in cases where
> the analysis process produces multiple tokens at the same position.**
> Under the hood these terms are expanded to a special synonym query
> that blends term frequencies, which does not support fuzzy expansion.

**Pay attention to the bold part, fuzziness is not applied to token at the same position**,

now let's inspect the token generated for your search term `hell world`.

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "hell",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0 // position 0 for hell
        },
        {
            "token": "hellworld",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 0,  // again position 0 for 
            "positionLength": 2 
        },
        {
            "token": "world",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1    //position 1 
        }
    ]
}
```

So for position 0 tokens `hell` and `hellworld` fuzziness will not be applied hence it doesn't match the index token `hello` and doesn't return any result.

Now inspect the tokens of `world hell`

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "world",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "worldhell",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 0,
            "positionLength": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "hell",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1   // this hell position is unique as 1 so it fuzziness will be applied.
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now when you query with `world hell`, on `hell` token `fuzziness` will be applied and it would match the `hello` indexed tokens and returns the search result.**

You can again change the search term to `world hell elastic` so now `hell` will not have a unique position, so it won't bring search results again. Hope this will clear your concepts.

Comment: The two file `analysis/char_filter.txt` and `analysis/synonym_filter.txt` is exactly empty. And I tried to define `my_analyzer` just using `lowercase`  and `shingle_analyzer`. The analyzer works well. I used analyze api and get the result same as yours. But  the search result is still same as before. It cannot hit the document with `hell world`. How did you manage the code?

Comment: @Phoenix, I am not using the code to get the search result, I just used the search query in JSON format(provided in my answer) please try this query on your data and see if you get search result.

Comment: I used *kibana dev tools* to send search request with JSON format. I tried get tokens with analyze API. It returns three tokens `hell`, `hellworld` and `world` as expect. But when I using search API, it just return nothing. I changed search analyzer to `standard` and it hit the docment. So I'm really confused now.

Comment: @Phoenix, can you again provide the screen-shot of kibana dev-tools, which you removed, I guess I got the issue here, you had just indexed a single doc containing `hello` and trying searching for `hell world` and `world hell`, you just need to have proper indexed documents ie `hello world` than `hell world` or `world hell` both search query works

Comment: I posted the screen-shot again.

Comment: @Phoenix, thanks, and just want to confirm you have just one doc containing `hello` in your index?? also provide the screen-shot of  analyze API of `hello` , `hell world` and `world hell`

Comment: Yes, there's only one document in the index. And I posted the screen-shot of analyze result.